# From an included file, how do I tell which file included it?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, server-side-includes

I've got a file called header.asp that is included in almost all the pages of my site using a SSI:

`<!-- #include file="header.asp" -->`

In header.asp I want to output some html depending on which file included it. Assume that the file being request is the file that includes header.asp.   In PHP, I can check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the file that was requested.  How can I get this information in ASP?

Comment: Have you tried Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_URI") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the page, you can use:

```
Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_URI")
```

I'm not sure how to get the immediate page the included the "header.asp" file, especially in the case of nested includes, or if you are even asking that.

Comment: I figured this would be the solution. Wasn't sure if ASP handled it the same way that PHP does.

Comment: Finally got access to the dev server and tried it out.  Turns out "REQUEST_URI" doesn't exist for some reason, but "PATH_INFO" gets the job done just as well.